# Prevent thread from closing even after program has been closed

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, process

Sorry if this question has already been asked.

I want to create a Background Thread (in C++) and start it when my main Application starts.(My main application is a Console App).

Now, the Background Thread's purpose is to execute tasks assigned by the Application, and more importantly do clean ups when the Application closes.

I want that if some one closes the main application the thread will keep running in background and do all the cleanups ...

When ever the main app closes the clean ups should start.

I have though of a few solution ideas :

- Have a separate Process started by main Application (running in the background) and use inter process communication to send tasks.

But I feel that this is too much for just the cleanups.

- I think that i could write a small Service for this but this is too platform specific.

Note : My main target platform is Windows.

(But I want to keep the scope of adding other platform support without rewriting the entire thing again.)

Comment: Under what circumstances do you expect, and want to cleanly handle, the main thread exiting?

Comment: @Sneftel mainly when the user click X , or kills task from task manager or equivalent